# rsync NOT changed file

Tags: linux, file, rsync

It is possible to rsync file even if it wasn't changed.

Let say I have file on src, and the same file on dest

when I do "rsync src dest" I want to force to download some specific file even if it is the same( have the same size, timestamp etc.)

Is this possible? --include doesn't work is there some other option for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ rsync --whole-file --modify-window=-1 src dest
```

`--modify-window=-1` tricks rsync into believing the timestamps of the files differ even when they don't.

`--whole-file` makes sure entire files are copied.

Assuming `src` and `dest` are directories, a complete command to test it might look like:

```
$ rsync -a -v --progress --whole-file --modify-window=-1 src dest
```

Run it twice to verify it copies everything every time.

Answer (score 0):

try the `cp -R` command, this copies really everything.

`rsync` is designed to save bytes to be transferred by transferring the different files only.

Comment: Will not work over a network though, OP doesn't say if it's localhost only.

Comment: what about mounting network as a local mount, ... then it does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is only to recopy same file then you can use

**scp src dest**

Comment: If I'm using rsync for running a scheduled backup, I prefer to keep it all rsync rather than fall back to scp. @grebneke's method works.